# I have code that performs a search on 2 large tables using a wildcard predicate

Tags: sql

When searching for an exact value, using the below SQL, the results are returned within 25 seconds. However, when using the `LIKE` keyword and wildcards, the result is never returned (we have to cancel the query).

The wildcard query replaces the penultimate line with `AND A.VENDOR_NO LIKE '%526000802'`

I have tried adding an index to the table on just the Vendor_no but no help.

```
SELECT A.AGY AS AGY, A.VENDOR_NO AS VENDOR_NO,                                 

'****' CONCAT SUBSTR(A.VENDOR_NO,5,6) AS VENDOR_NO_MASKED,                     

A.VENDOR_NAME AS VENDOR_NAME, A.FY AS FY, A.EFFECTIVE_DATE AS 
EFFECTIVE_DATE,  
A.BATCH_AGY AS BATCH_AGY, A.BATCH_DATE AS BATCH_DATE,                          
A.BATCH_TYPE AS BATCH_TYPE,                                                    
A.BATCH_NO AS BATCH_NO, A.BATCH_SEQ_NO AS BATCH_SEQ_NO,                        
A.INVOICE_NO AS INVOICE_NO,                                                    
A.INVOICE_DESC AS INVOICE_DESC, A.WARRANT_WRIT_DATE AS WARRANT_WRIT_DATE,      
A.WARRANT_NO AS WARRANT_NO, A.ARCHIVE_REF_NO AS ARCHIVE_REF_NO,                
A.CUR_DOC_NO AS CUR_DOC_NO, A.CUR_DOC_SFX AS CUR_DOC_SFX,                      
A.REF_DOC_NO AS REF_DOC_NO,                                                    
A.REF_DOC_SFX AS REF_DOC_SFX, B.GLA AS GLA, A.TCODE AS TCODE, A.PCA AS PCA,   
A.OBJECT AS OBJECT, A.COBJ AS COBJ, A.AOBJ AS AOBJ, A.INDEX_CODE AS 
INDEX_CODE,
A.APPN_NO AS APPN_NO, A.APPD_FUND AS APPD_FUND, A.FUND AS FUND,                
B.GL_POST_AMT AS GL_POST_AMT                                                   
FROM A60PRD.TB_ADT1_ARCH A LEFT OUTER JOIN A60PRD.TB_ADTG_NEW B                
ON A.AGY = B.AGY AND A.BATCH_AGY = B.BATCH_AGY                                 
AND A.BATCH_DATE = B.BATCH_DATE AND A.BATCH_TYPE = B.BATCH_TYPE                
AND A.BATCH_NO = B.BATCH_NO AND A.BATCH_SEQ_NO = B.BATCH_SEQ_NO
AND A.TRANS_ID_SFX = B.TRANS_ID_SFX                            
WHERE A.AGY BETWEEN 'AAA' AND '999'                                                             
AND (GLA = '3500' OR GLA = '3501')                             
AND (CUR_DOC_NO LIKE 'V%' OR CUR_DOC_NO LIKE 'D%') 
AND A.VENDOR_NO = '1526000802'            
ORDER BY AGY, BATCH_AGY, FY, EFFECTIVE_DATE ;
```

Comment: Any Explain or Execution plan output? Which dbms are you using? Table definitions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is no need to write everything upper case in SQL.

Comment: Removed duplicate code and instead explained the single change to the code. 
Removed necessary appeals for help
Ensured detail of the issue needed to be solved was provided immediately.  

You had all the information available in the question, just made it more presentable.

Answer (score 1):

That LIKE is actually an *ends-with* check. If your SQL supports the `REVERSE(string)` function you can maintain a reversed index

```
AND A.VENDOR_NO_REVERSED LIKE '208000625%'
```

Additionally add an index on VARCHAR VENDOR_NO_REVERSED.

Alternatively (more a hack) add an indexed field `VENDOR_NO_LAST = MOD(VENDOR_NO, 1000)` and a condition `AND VENDOR_NO_LAST = 802`. This scales less well and is slower.

Answer (score 0):

You have exchanged an equality operator with a `LIKE` expression, which often results in performance drawbacks, if the database is not tuned respectively.

In your case, the `%` wildcard is at the start of the like-expression. Most likely this renders index usage during tree traversal impossible. Your statement will have to do full table scans, which is bad for runtime performance.

See e.g. https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning